# Netbeans RCP app installer not working?

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

I bundled my JRE with my netbeans RCP installer which worked fine on my windows 7(32 bit machine). But when i tried on an XP(32 bit) machine it says, "Cannot prepare bundled JVM with installer. Most probably the bundled JVM is not compatible with the current platform." I tried to verbose the installation and found an Exit code : 1006 (Timeout during process execution).

This is a part of the verbosed output:

```
extracting: C:\DOCUME~1\E567467\LOCALS~1\Temp\\NBI30104.tmp\_jvm/lib/zi/EST  
inflating: C:\DOCUME~1\E567467\LOCALS~1\Temp\\NBI30104.tmp\_jvm/lib/zi/EST5EDT  
creating: C:\DOCUME~1\E567467\LOCALS~1\Temp\\NBI30104.tmp\_jvm/lib/zi/Etc/
inflating: C:\DOCUME~1\E567467\LOCALS~1\Temp\\NBI30104.tmp\_jvm/lib/zi/Etc/GMT  
extracting: C:\DOCUME~1\E567467\LOCALS~1\Temp\\NBI30104.tmp\_jvm/lib/zi/Etc/GMT+1  
inflating: C:\DOCUME~1\E567467\LOCALS~1\Temp\\NBI30104.tmp\_jvm/lib/zi/Etc/GMT+10  
extracting: C:\DOCUME~1\E567467\LOCALS~1\Temp\\NBI30104.tmp\_jvm/lib/zi/Etc/GMT+11  
inflating: C:\DOCUME~1\E567467\LOCALS~1\Temp\\NBI30104.tmp\_jvm/lib/zi/Etc/GMT+12  
inflating: C:\DOCUME~1\E567467\LOCALS~1\Temp\\NBI30104.tmp\_jvm/lib/zi/Etc/GMT+2  
extracting: C:\DOCUME~1\E567467\LOCALS~1\Temp\\NBI30104.tmp\_jvm/lib/zi/Etc/GMT+3  
inflating: C:\DOCUME~1\E567467\LOCALS~1\Temp\\NBI30104.tmp\_jvm/lib/zi/Etc/GMT+4  
extracting: C:\DOCUME~1\E567467\LOCALS~1\Temp\\NBI30104.tmp\_jvm/lib/zi/Etc/GMT+5  
inflating: C:\DOCUME~1\E567467\LOCALS~1\Temp\\NBI30104.tmp\_jvm/lib/zi/Etc/GMT+6  
extracting: C:\DOCUME~1\E567467\LOCALS~1\Temp\\NBI30104.tmp\_jvm/lib/zi/Etc/GMT+7  
inflating: C:\DOCUME~1\E567467\LOCALS~1\Temp\\NBI30104.tmp\_jvm/lib/zi/Etc/GMT+8              [2012-11-27 22:04:34.757]> ... process is timeouted
[2012-11-27 22:04:34.897]> ... terminate process
[2012-11-27 22:04:34.944]> ... could not extract JVM : timeout
[2012-11-27 22:04:35.007]> ... error occured during JVM extraction
[2012-11-27 22:04:35.022]> ... no java was found
[2012-11-27 22:41:01.059]> No compatible jvm was found on the system
[2012-11-27 22:41:01.090]> ... deleting temporary directory 
[2012-11-27 22:41:02.090]> ... EXIT status : 1009
[2012-11-27 22:41:02.122]> ... EXIT code : 1006
[2012-11-27 22:41:02.168]> Closing launcher properties
```

Could someone please help me resolve this?

Thanks

Ajai

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a different version of Java on your XP machine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I dont think that is the reason because my installer will be using the bundled JRE after extracting it. Problem occurs while extracting the bundled jre.